# How to send big files using ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

So currently I'm working on a simple project where users gets to upload an image to server. Before I mention my problem here is how I'm doing it:

Client:

```
var dataURL = sendingcanvas.toDataURL("image/*");
var imagedatatosend = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
formdata = {
    'image': imagedatatosend
};

$.ajax({
    url: '../receive',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formdata,
    encode: false,
    success: function(result){
         alert(result);
    }
});
```

FYI: `imagedatatosend` size is lower than 5MB and contains exactly the file data selected.

Basically What happens Is that users select an image using `<input type="file"` tag Then I'm setting that selected file drawn in a `canvas` to convert it to base64 and send it to server.

Java Server:

```
String datareceived = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

byte[] bImg = Base64.decodeBase64(datareceived.getBytes("UTF-8"));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("hi.jpg");
fos.write(bImg);
fos.close();
```

I think I might not need to explain what the code above does. But I'm facing some serious performance problem I mean It takes some huge time to write the data to `hi.jpg` file, even if I try `System.out.println(datareceived);` It takes seconds for my mouse click to respond on server console.

I don't know why is it happening, Do I need to send the image data as multipart or what?

All replies are appreciated and Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: This sounds like an exclusively Java problem, you may want to remove some of the tags on your question.

Comment: I don't think there's an `encode` option in `$.ajax`, you should be setting `processData` and `contentType` both to `false`, but that wouldn't be neccessary when you're sending a B64 string instead of an actual image

Comment: @adeneo I just added both `processData` and `contentType` with value of false, But no luck still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLHttpRequest and FormData to append the file. It will be sent using multipart and chunked appropriately.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects